# Does acetone react with acidic precipitate product in this reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

In this reaction procedure, It seems like there is a mistake in step 3 which would result in a 0% yield. From step 3, it looks like everything is fine, its performing the acid catalysed hydrolysis of Nitriles to form a carboxylic acid, and the reaction is maintained in its acidic conditions meaning the carboxylic group would be neutral and will precipitate in the aqueous condition. Could this mistake be when we wash the acid precipitate with acetone?
Does acetone react with mesitylacetic acid?

Step 1: Chloromethylmesitylene 3. Mesitylene 2 (200 g, 1.66 moles), 1 L of
concentrated hydrochloric acid (1 L), and formaldehyde solution (63 mL, 0.84
mole) were placed in a round bottomed flask. Hydrogen chloride was introduced
below the surface of the mixture through a gas inlet tube. The mixture was stirred
vigorously and heated to keep the temperature of the mixture at 55-60 °C for 5.5
hours. At the halfway point, additional formaldehyde solution (63 mL, 0.84 mole)
was added. After the mixture had been cooled to room temperature, it was
extracted with ether (3 x 300 mL). The combined ether extracts were washed
successively with water, dilute sodium hydroxide, and brine, dried over sodium
sulfate, and filtered. The ether was removed and the residue was distilled under
reduced pressure (130–131°/22 mm) to give chloromethylmesitylene 3 (155–170
g); the distillate solidified to a crystalline mass (mp 37-38 °C).

Step 2: Mesitylacetonitrile 4. A solution of sodium cyanide, (66.2 g) in water (110
mL) and ethanol (160 mL) was heated at reflux until all the sodium cyanide had
dissolved. Chloromethylmesitylene 3 (152.5 g, 0.90 mole) was then added
slowly, and the heating was continued for 3 hours. The mixture was allowed to
cool to room temperature and extracted with ether (3 x 300 mL). The organic
extracts were washed with water, dried over sodium sulfate and filtered. After
removal of the ether, the residue was distilled under reduced pressure (160–
165°/22 mmHg) to give mesitylacetonitrile 4 (128–133 g) which solidified upon
standing.

Step 3: Mesitylacetic acid 1.
Concentrated sulfuric acid (750 mL) was cautiously added to water (900 mL).
When the mixture had cooled to about 50 °C, mesitylacetonitrile 4 (127 g, 0.80
mole) was added. The mixture was heated at reflux. A precipitate formed during
heating. The contents of the flask were cooled and poured into ice water (3 L).
The precipitate was collected on a Büchner funnel, **washed well with acetone** and dried in a vacuum desiccator to give mesitylacetic acid 1 (123 g), mp 163–166
°C.

[image]

Comment: I think it unlikely there will be a reaction with the acetone if the product 1 is quenched into ice water first. If you are concerned about the possibility chill your acetone wash solution before use.